# Jasmine 2.0 Timeout error for async request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Recently I started taking a peek in testing my JavaScript application with Jasmine. I tried to implement my first test for an asynchronous request, but I receive a timeout error and I do not know why.

My backend service:

```
formularGenerator.factory("backendConnector", ["$http", function ($http) {
    var BC = {};

    BC.getFormularSpecification = function (callback) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/response.json'
        }).then(function (response, status) {
            callback(response.data);
        },function (error){
            callback(error);
        });
    }

    return BC;
}]);
```

My test for the asynchronous request:

```
describe("backendConnector", function() {
    var backendConnector, httpBackend, fsResponse;

    beforeEach(module('formularGenerator'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_backendConnector_, $httpBackend) {
        backendConnector = _backendConnector_;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    }));

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        backendConnector.getFormularSpecification(
            function(formularSpecification) {
                fsResponse = formularSpecification;
                done();
            }
        )
    });

    it("should not return an empty JSON", function() {
        expect(fsResponse).not.toEqual({});
    });
});
```

My error:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Why do I get this error? The request may be asynchronous but in my case it definitely does not exceed the timeout interval of jasmine. (I even tried to extend the timeout interval...)

How can I make my test work?